# How can i solve the error internal PostCss Failed to load when running npm run dev?

Tags: laravel, npm

Here is the error message that i am getting:

```
> node:internal/process/promises:288
>             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
>             ^
> 
> [Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config
> (searchPath: /home/amaya/Desktop/LOANSPUR/prime-crm): [Error] Loading
> PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer' Require
> stack:
> - /home/amaya/Desktop/LOANSPUR/prime-crm/postcss.config.js
> 
> (@/home/amaya/Desktop/LOANSPUR/prime-crm/postcss.config.js) Error:
> Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
> Require stack:
> - /home/amaya/Desktop/LOANSPUR/prime-crm/postcss.config.js
> 
> (@/home/amaya/Desktop/LOANSPUR/prime-crm/postcss.config.js)
>     at load (file:///home/amaya/Desktop/LOANSPUR/prime-crm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-8609dc5d.js:36388:11)
>     at file:///home/amaya/Desktop/LOANSPUR/prime-crm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-8609dc5d.js:36413:16
>     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
>     at plugins (file:///home/amaya/Desktop/LOANSPUR/prime-crm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-8609dc5d.js:36412:8)
>     at processResult (file:///home/amaya/Desktop/LOANSPUR/prime-crm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-8609dc5d.js:36482:14)
>     at file:///home/amaya/Desktop/LOANSPUR/prime-crm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-8609dc5d.js:36606:14]
> 
> Node.js v18.16.0
```

How can i solve it?

This is what i have tried:

I have run:

```
1. npm update

2.npm install
```

then when i run again npm run dev,the same error is there.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following and it has worked.

1.i run `npm update;`

2.`npm install autoprefixer;`

3.`npm run dev;`

I did those 3 steps and the error was solved

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Laravel Breeze package, you may encounter an error while running the npm run dev command.

Error Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/y5XzQ7AlBZoC

To resolve this issue, follow these steps:

1. Open the postcss.config.js file. Replace the existing code with the
   updated code.

   //Old code

   ```
   export default {
       plugins: {
          tailwindcss: {},
          autoprefixer: {},
       },

   };
   ```

   // New code

   ```
   module.exports = {
       plugins: {
           tailwindcss: {},
           autoprefixer: {},
       },
     };
   ```
2. Run npm run dev again.

Error fix screenshot: https://prnt.sc/NjpyNVeF8iR3

By following these steps, you should be able to fix the error and successfully run the npm run dev command without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and realized there was a conflict in my .local try clear cache or change folder path or name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).